# React day picker return all data when expecting only day

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

So I'm using react-day-picker, for calendar.

```
import DayPickerInput from 'react-day-picker/DayPickerInput';
import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';
```

This is the function I use :

```
<DayPickerInput  onDayChange={day => this.onEduGraduateFromChange(d, day)}  />
```

The thing is function day=> return lot of thing like:

```
Wed Aug 07 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Time)
```

when this is the expected format: `2019-08-07`

How can I get this?

My function send data over the app, so I don't need all that stuff like time etc.. just day/month/year  it is possible?

How can I get the expected format?

I try day instead of date but without effort.

```
onDayChange={date => this.onEduGraduateFromChange(d, date)}
```

I use `console.log` to output the whole json data and I got

```
graduateFrom: 'Wed Aug 07 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Time)'
```

I expected the output day/month/year, but the actual output is

```
Wed Aug 07 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Time)
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete, minimal code sample? I don't understand your problem

Comment: done, code sample updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this [docs](https://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/input/) for more insights

In `onDayChange` you can do this=>

```
import dateFnsFormat from 'date-fns/format';
let date = dateFnsFormat(day,'DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log(date)
```

Comment: that is awesome solution :D i was looking for something like that. Thanks bro